# jQuery ajax call promise fails even though HTTP status is 200 on Android PhoneGap/Cordova

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

On my Android device, using jQuery in a PhoneGap/Cordova app, a call to `jQuery.ajax()` or `$.ajax()` fails (rejected promise) even though the returned status code is HTTP 200.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when the call needs to be using the JSONP call pattern.

However, in this case, the jqXHR object would have a statusText property value of "load". This happened because all HTTPS traffic on the Android device would return an invalid SSL certificate warning. This caused the jQuery ajax call to fail with status of "load".

Performing a Factory Reset of Android on the device helped to resolve this issue.